# Tikz - How to draw the following graph without knowing the equation. [flipped ln x]

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This is the graph I am trying to draw.
[image: Graph I am trying to draw]

My humble effort till now:

> ```
>     \begin{tikzpicture}
>       \begin{axis}[
>         height = 4cm, width = 10cm,
>         xmin=0,xmax=500,
>         ymin=0,ymax=200,
>         grid=both,
>         grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
>         major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
>         axis lines=middle,
>         enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
>         xtick = {0,50,...,500},
>         ytick = {0,50,...,200},
>         scatter/use mapped color= {draw=black},
>         xlabel = Number of months,
>         ylabel = Balance
>     ]
>     \end{axis}
>     \draw (0,1.8) to [bend left=15] (6.7,0);
>     \draw [dashed] (0,1.8) to [bend left=25] (6.7, 0);
>     \end{tikzpicture}
> ```

Comment: Is there any reason why you put flipped `ln x` in parentheses?

Comment: actually often I come across questions " How to draw THIS graph" and you have to open it up and see what the figure is.  So I thought to add a little detail for future users who might be looking for a similar question. 
Above graph had a shape similar to shifted and flipped `ln x`, so I thought that might be helpful search term

Comment: Something like `25 ln(400 -x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess the functions, I'd bet on some elliptical arcs "distorted" by some powers. This is because the slopes at 0 or 400 appear to be 0 or infinite, respectively. Hence I have the following proposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid (10,4);
\foreach \x in {0,50,...,500}
{\draw (\x/50,0)--(\x/50,-0.2) node[below]{\x};}
\foreach \y in {0,50,...,200}
{\draw (0,\y/50)--(-0.2,\y/50) node[left]{\y};}
\draw[thick,variable=\x,domain=0:90,blue] plot ({8*cos(\x)},{3*sin(\x)}); 
\draw[thick,variable=\x,domain=0:90,blue,dashed] plot ({8*pow(cos(\x),3/4)},
{3*pow(sin(\x),2/3)}); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I asked this question before too. How are you able to predict the equations. It is pretty awesome.

Comment: @urwaCFC I would be better off if I could predict the lotto numbers ;-) More seriously, I tried to describe the reasoning in the answer: "This is because the slopes at 0 or 400 appear to be 0 or infinite, respectively." These are the features of an ellipse. And it is also obvious that taking the square root, or, more generally, a power between 0 and 1, of the coordinates will leave them unchanged when they are 1 but increase them when they are smaller.

Answer (score 5):

**edit:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    height = 4cm, width = 10cm,
    xmin=0,xmax=500,
    ymin=0,ymax=200,
    grid=both,
    xtick = {0,50,...,500},
    xlabel = Number of months,
    ylabel = Balance
]
\draw           (0,150) .. controls +(100, 0) and +(-50,25) .. (300,100)
                        .. controls +(50,-25) and +(-10,25) .. (400,0);
\draw [dashed]  (0,150) -- + (200,0) 
                        .. controls +(75,  0) and +(-25,30) .. (350,100)
                        .. controls +(25,-30) and +(- 5,25) .. (400,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

an alternative, different approach (usual with `pgfplots`):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    height = 4cm, width = 10cm,
    xmin=0,xmax=500,
    ymin=0,ymax=200,
    grid=both,
    no marks,
    xtick = {0,50,...,500},
    xlabel = Number of months,
    ylabel = Balance
]
\addplot +[domain=0:400,thick,smooth] coordinates    
    {(0,150) (100,145) (200,138) (250,125) (300,100) (350, 60) (400,0)};
\addplot +[domain=0:400,smooth, dashed] coordinates
    {(0,150) (100,150) (200,150) (250,145) (300,133) (350,100) (400,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

if you somewhere calculate both curves, you can add more coordinates (now more or less poorly estimated from your graph).

Comment: can the bottom line pass through (300,150) point and dotted line move slightly above and pass through (350, 100). This is what I am basically struggling with.

Comment: @urwaCFC, see edited answer. for different curves you just play with its coordinates.

Comment: I am really sorry I meant ( 300, 100) as can be seen from the graph. Basically, I want what you can see in the image I have attached. As you can see your graph remains at 150 for too long to be accurate.

Comment: @urwaCFC, i rewrote my answer. see if now gives more opportunities to reproduce your graphs.

Comment: +1... This approach is the best in my opinion too (just wrote this in my answer and show you did it.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with using the points that we can "read" and the angles we can recognize:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}



\begin{document}




        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[
            height = 6cm, width = 10cm,
            xmin=0,xmax=500,
            ymin=0,ymax=200,
            grid=both,
            grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
            major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
            axis lines=middle,
            enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
            xtick = {0,50,...,500},
            ytick = {0,50,...,200},
            scatter/use mapped color= {draw=black},
            xlabel = Number of months,
            ylabel = Balance
            ]
            \draw (axis cs:0,150) to [in=150,out=0] (axis cs:300,100);
            \draw (axis cs:300,100) to [in=120,out=-30] (axis cs:375,50);
            \draw (axis cs:375,50) to [in=90,out=-60] (axis cs:400,0);
            \draw [dashed]  (axis cs:0,150) to [in=135,out=0] (axis cs:350,100);
            \draw[dashed](axis cs:350,100)to[out=-45, in=90](axis cs:400,0);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Hint: 
(imagine an analog clock:
3 o'clock=0 degrees
9 o'clock-180 degrees
12 =90 degrees
)

Then:
"in" is the angle in which the line uses to get in the final point.
"out" is the angle which the line uses to get out of the starting point.

The above angles in respect to our more above watch angles.

Output:

[image]

**EDIT: (Improving points after OP request)**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}



\begin{document}




        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[
            height = 6cm, width = 10cm,
            xmin=0,xmax=500,
            ymin=0,ymax=200,
            grid=both,
            grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
            major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
            axis lines=middle,
            enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
            xtick = {0,50,...,500},
            ytick = {0,50,...,200},
            scatter/use mapped color= {draw=black},
            xlabel = Number of months,
            ylabel = Balance
            ]
            \draw (axis cs:0,150) to[in=175,out=0](100,146);
            \draw (axis cs:100,146)to [in=166,out=-5] (axis cs:150,140);
            \draw (axis cs:150,140)to[in=161,out=-14](axis cs:200,130);
            \draw (axis cs:200,130) to [in=153,out=-19] (axis cs:300,100);
            \draw (axis cs:300,100) to [in=139,out=-27] (axis cs:350,72);
            \draw (axis cs:350,72) to[in=126,out=-41](axis cs:375,50);
            \draw (axis cs:375,50) to [in=88,out=-54](axis cs:400,0);
            \draw [dashed]  (axis cs:0,150) to [in=180.2,out=0] (axis cs:200,149);
            \draw[dashed](axis cs:200,149)to[in=135,out=-0.2](axis cs:350,100);
            \draw[dashed](axis cs:350,100)to[out=-45, in=90](axis cs:400,0);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can both line stay below 150 on y axis. And can the bend in bottom line be removed. Making the graph more smooth like in the image. This is what I am basically struggling with. i.e customizing the graph lines.

Comment: @urwaCFC This is the idea... but without function you need many tests to force a graph pass from specific points and with specific angle etc... I improved a little bit the result, but will not do more tests... You can do it yourself... (Hint: my way gives smoother function with small amount of points and can not really be used with many points... using plot with coordinates and the appropriate tension would be a better approach if you need such accuracy).